# Transition not working properly on vue when div is being hiding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have simple transition to toggle a div text, however the transition works only when the text is being hiding, however when I click to show the text the transition doesn't work here it is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <transition name="fade">
        <div v-if="this.showName">My name is Simon</div>
    </transition>
    <button @click="showName = !showName">Toggle</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data(){
      return {
          showName: false,
      }
    },

    name: "StatusComponent"
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.fade-enter-from{
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-to{
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade-enter-active{
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
.fade-leave-from{
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade-leave-to{
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-leave-active{
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <p  v-if="showName">My name is Simon</p>
</div>
```

You should open a p tag under the div tag